# Brainf*ck input interpretation

Tags: python, interpreter, brainfuck

I am writing Brainfuck interpreter in Python and I'm currently testing this code:

```
,>++++++[<-------->-],[<+>-]<.
```

with this input:

```
43
```

Polish Wikipedia said the result should be 7, but something is not right here. How should I treat the input? As 4 and 3 or as: '4' and '3' (52 and 51)?
If I treat input characters as integers then result is -41, because after first loop [0] is -44 and [1] is 0, then [1] becomes 3 and we add that 3 to -44 so it results in -41.

On the other hand if I treat input characters as ASCII codes then after the first loop [0] is 4 and [1] is 0, then [1] becomes 51 and we add that 51 to 4 so it results in 55. (this JavaScript interpreter also gives result 55: https://www.nayuki.io/page/brainfuck-interpreter-javascript)

However, I downloaded some interpreter written in C and it gives result 7, the same as Wikipedia told... so I am confused. There is that interpreter: http://pastebin.com/aasxLppa , also this interpreter gives result 7: brainfuck.tk -.-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inputs are `4` and `3`, as bytes. The input is taken as ASCII characters, the values are thus 52 and 51.

- The first input is decremented by 8, 6 times, so 52 - 48 = 4.
- The second input is added to the first input, so 4 plus 51 = 55.
- 55 is written to the output, and that is ASCII `7`.

The program sums up two ASCII digits.

The JavaScript interpreter is entirely correct. You were looking at the first register, which holds the byte value of `55`, but the *output* box shows `7`, the ASCII character.